# Change user profiles on the platform Android

Tags: android

I write in the language java for android. The problem is this - how do I change the user profile in the job time? It is necessary that the application is admissible in 9:00 switched to silent mode?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by changing the user profile? And what does it have to do with silent mode?

Comment: Sorry,profile settings - standard, mute, vibration...